# Bold text in mfc application

Tags: mfc, bold

How can I bold text in mfc application like in word office when i mark bold icon in toolbar that made my text bold that I before enter in dialog window?
I made dialog window for new text and toolbar icon and now I have problem with making text bold.

Comment: Please show some code with what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Word display text in an owner-drawn window. It uses the API to draw the text. As you look into the API, you'll see there are options for font name, size, bold, etc. The exact details depend on which APIs you use to draw the text.

In your case, it's hard to say as you really haven't provided enough details. What kind of window is it that you want to make bold? Is the window owner-drawn?

If it is owner-drawn, modify the code that draws it. If not, is it an MFC window? If so, look at changing the `Font` property. (There is an example in the question [MFC: Changing font of a List control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271845/mfc-changing-font-of-a-list-control).

If that's not specific enough, then you really need to write a better question.