# Font size in Dialog List View

Tags: list, mfc, dialog

I want to make the font larger in the List View section of the dialog box. Messing around, I got it to change by selecting an alternate font (with a larger size) in the OnCtlColor function. However, the next line doesn't move down far enough and overlays half of the first line. There appears to be no way to select the font when defining the control, so I am very open to suggestion...

Thanks,
Gene Moore

Comment: Maybe try the `WM_SETFONT` message instead? Send it once, during initialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MFC: Changing font of a List control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271845/mfc-changing-font-of-a-list-control)

Comment: Show us the code, how you are trying this.